# Mac check in GCM failed

Tags: java, security, kotlin, cryptography

When I call `cipher.doFinal()` method return mac check-in GCM failed

```
fun decrypt(key: SecretKey, input: OperationResult): Input {
        val gcmSpec = GCMParameterSpec(tagLength * 8, input.iv)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithmName)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmSpec)
        cipher.updateAAD(input.aad)
        val data = cipher.doFinal(input.data + input.tag)
        return Input(data = data, aad = input.aad)
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide the error. Moreover, some sample data, imports and library will help others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Well, such an error happens whenever the key, iv, AAD, authentication tag or ciphertext has been altered. That, unfortunately, doesn't really narrow it down. Without more information, this question is not answerable in any way.